# HTML video player than chooses a random file, autoplays it, then waits 5 minutes and starts the script again

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm trying to make a webpage that has a video player with no controls. The video player picks a random video from a list, plays it, waits 5 minutes then picks another random video from the list and plays it, on and on forever.

I've been given the following code, but it doesn't work. No video is played when I load the page.

The directory contains the code in a single HTML file, and 3 WEBM files (vidplayer.html 1.webm 2.webm 3.webm).

```
    <html>
    <body>
        <video id="video" width=800 height=600 muted autoplay> <\video>

        <script>
            var vidList = ["1.webm", "2.webm", "3.webm"];

            var video = document.getElementById("video");

            function randInt(min, max) {
                return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
            }

            video.src = vidList[randInt(0,3)];

            while(true){
                setTimeout(video.src = vidList[randInt(0,3)], 300000) ;
            }
        <\script>
    <\body>
    <\html>
```

Comment: Tags are closed with `/`, not with \. Everything else looks fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch out the closing html tags: `<\script>` should be `</script>` and so on.

Your **while(true)** is an endless loop and is creating infinite timeouts.

You probably wanted to do:

```
setInterval(function changeVideo() {
  video.src = vidList[randInt(0, 2)];
}, 300000);
```

setInterval will be called indefinitely each 300000 milliseconds.

This has the same result as doing setTimeout call itself:

```
setTimeout(function changeVideo() {
  video.src = vidList[randInt(0, 2)];
  setTimeout(changeVideo, 300000);
}, 300000);
```

If you want a number between 0 and 2 for your three videos you should call `randInt(0, 2)` the way randInt is created.

You can see it working, with a couple of videos and a 15 secs delay between videos [here](https://codepen.io/jeprubio/pen/XWmRpGJ)